# React Native List and Grid - how to achieve active color for icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am trying to apply an active color for the clicked icon(List and Grid) but couldn't find a correct solution since new into RN. I have pasted the component code separately for someone's reference.

CODE:

```
export default class Gallery extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    gridView: true,
    iconColor: "#ccc"
  };

  changeViewList = () => {
    this.setState({ gridView: false });
  };
  changeViewGrid = () => {
    this.setState({ gridView: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { imageData, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={this.changeViewGrid}>
              <Icon name="th-large" size={25} color={this.state.iconColor} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={this.changeViewList}>
             <Icon name="list" size={25} style={styles.iconAlign} color= {this.state.iconColor} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnDesign: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#e45",
    width: "30%",
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  btnText: {
    color: "#fff",
    textAlign: "center",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

Image reference:

[image: app image]

**Expected would be:**

*List View*

[image]

*Grid View*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator inside the color prop to colorize the icon depending on a variable.

```
// if the this.state.gridView is true colorize the icon green otherwise take the standard color 
<Icon name="th-large" size={25} color={this.state.gridView ? 'green' : this.state.iconColor } />
```

and here you can do it the other way around:

```
// if this.state.gridView is true, take the regular color otherwise use make it green 
<Icon name="list" size={25} style={styles.iconAlign} color= {this.state.gridView ? this.state.iconColor : 'green' } />
```

Comment: firstly thanks for your prompt response. Unfortunately, this condition would apply to both icons in the same state.

Comment: @SenthilSivaramakrishnan It takes the same state, but it exactly works the other way around. If gridView is enabled the th-large icon is green and the list is gray. If the gridView is disabled the list icon is green and th-large icon is gray. I switched the conditions

Comment: @SenthilSivaramakrishnan but of course you can also add another condition, but it will work the same way.

Comment: since I have only *gridView: true* in the state and I understand from your comment is that need to add one more state as *listView: false*. Kindly correct me if I am wrong